# Are thugs more likely to kick or punch?

Tags: kicking

Ok correct me if I'm wrong but bullies tend to kick (low kick) instead of punching. I know this because there's this bully/thug (I can handle him, leg kicks are just his main attacks) who likes to kick people in the legs. So is it correct that thugs kick more than punch?

Comment: So what I mean is that is it true that bullies kick more than punch?

Comment: Are you making an assumption about the behavior of all thugs or bullies based on limited observation of one? I'd suggest that "thugs" would typically mostly kick once the target is down, not when they're standing.

Answer (score 7):

I take your premise to be that low kicks are the standard attack of thugs in assault situations.

An extensive quantitative study on injuries from assault in the US [suggests otherwise](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm5121a3.htm):

> Most injuries were diagnosed as contusions (31%) or lacerations (23%), followed by fractures (10%), internal injuries (7%), punctures (7%), and strains or sprains (7%). **The parts of the body affected most were the head (54%), arms/hands (19%), and upper trunk (10%).**

Thus, at least assault that lead to injuries bad enough to be treated in hospital seems to be aimed mainly at the head and generally the upper body. Hand injuries suggest lacerated or broken fingers/knuckles, which is a common injury in street fights, especially when the head is attacked.

Additionally, contusions of the legs would count in and apparently make up less than 10% of the cases.

This is, admittedly, only counting in hospitalizations. On the other hand, police does suggest to go to the hospital if it is registered as an assault to make sure injuries are properly documented, even if the injuries are not that severe. So it should give a pretty good overall picture nevertheless.

My conclusion would be that your experience is anecdotal and cannot validly be taken as a standard case. My anecdotal experience is that most people try to use their arms and body to bring people down by pushs or wrestling and pummel them once on the ground, btw.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which invokes statistics. All I had was anecdotal information, and my own suppositions (most people lack the flexibility or coordination to throw a good kick without throwing themselves off balance). As noted by slugster in a comment, I suspect the calculus might change once someone goes to the ground. Against a grounded opponent, an untrained opponent will probably naturally go for a stomp or soccer kick to the ribs or the head.